# javascript how to read line by line from a local text fie and display in a listbox

Tags: javascript

Here I want to display a text file in a listbox, with one option for one line. Because thus I can dynamically change the line to display.

So how to read a text file in its own web server directory line by line? Then I can create option to display it.

Comment: Just make sure by "local" you mean its on a webserver

Comment: yeah, "local" means on its own web server

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you can't. Javascript cannot access the file system on the computer besides wherever the OS stores cookies for the particular browser in question. You would have to upload the file to the server, write server-side code to take the posted file, read it and display whatever you need in the Listbox.

You have to understand that Javascript runs inside the browser and the browser itself is sand-boxed. Your browser cannot access your local resources in general (speakers, hard-drive, printer, etc) unless you employ a plugin (Java Applet, ActiveX Control, Flash, Silverlight, etc.)

Comment: sorry I did not state it clearly. "local" means on its own web server

Comment: What kind of web server. What language are you using to program the web server? Are you using Node.js or something similar? If not, you can't read a file using javascript on the server side because javascript is executed on the *client side*.

Comment: I use python bottle package. I do not use Node.js. Basically, a text file is uploaded and I want to display it line by line

Answer (score 0):

You can't access to the local file system, because that would mean you can read all the files on one's computer. Howewer, you can get a particular file when the user drag and drops that file into an element.

Here's an example that shows you the content of the file if it is a txt document: http://html5demos.com/drag-anything

Comment: sorry I did not state it clearly. "local" means on its own web server